# I want to convert a 4x1 vector column to skew symmetric matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

for example

`Q=[a;b;c;d]`

S is skew symmetric which satisfies the condition -S= S^T

is that true the skew symmetric of Q is

```
S(Q) =[0   -a   d   -c
       a    0   c    b
      -d   -c   0   -a
       c   -b   a    0]   ?
```

and how do it in matlab directly ?

Comment: Note that you can create a skew-symmetric matrix from any matrix by subtracting its transposed: `A-A.'`. I'm not sure there is one specific skew symmetric matrix for a given vector. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135281-how-to-span-a-3-1-vector-into-a-3-3-skew-symmetric-matrix) is a very similar question where they define S differently than how you do. Are you trying to form the 4D equivalent of [the cross-product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your `S(Q)` is a skew symmetric matrix, since `S(i,j) == -S(j,i);`. I'm not sure what you meant by a skew symmetric matrix of `Q`, since with a given set of value, you can create many different skew symmetric matrices, for example:

```
S(Q) =[0   -a   b   -c
       a    0   c    d
      -b   -c   0   -a
       c   -d   a    0]
```

The above is also a skew symmetric matrix constructed using values of `Q`. Note that the positions of `b` and `d` are switched.

If your skew symmetric is only limited to 4x1 and takes the form specified in your question, then you can create a function for it:

```
function s=skew(q)

if numel(q) ~= 4
     error('Input vector must have 4 elements.')
end
s=[0 -q(1) q(4) -q(3)
   q(1) 0 q(3) q(2)
   -q(4) -q(3) 0 -q(1)
   q(3) -q(2) q(1) 0];
```

Then

```
skew_Q = skew(Q);
```